# PyCharm removes comments like `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences`

Tags: pycharm

If I do clean up my python source code with PyCharm, the commented line gets removed:

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import foolib
```

I want `import foolib` to be kept, even if I do optimize imports.

If I use this feature of pyCharm twice, then `import foolib` gets removed :-(

Is this a bug or a feature?

I use pyCharm version 2016.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a reported bug. You can find more information [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19837).

However note that is marked as a **Major** bug, so hopefully ti will get fixed soon.